# Compressing Javascript & CSS using Gzip

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter, .htaccess, gzip

OK, the question may sound familiar - and I've read answers about it everywhere BUT (before you point me to some other answer) **none** of that has worked for me *(htaccess modifications, gzip-ping beforehand, etc)*.

So, let me explain you the situation :

- My website is CodeIgniter-based
- I'm using XAMPP on Mac (for development purposes), so my actual testing address is something like `http://localhost/~drkameleon/mysitename`
- The only `.htaccess` file I've edited (and that, only for CI-oriented rewritting) resides on the very same directory as my CI installation

So, how do I enable JS/CSS gzip compression? (I don't really care even if the scripts are pre-compressed, they're 100% static anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

I have this through a controller that loads the css and javascript files in two different functions, then run this:

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
else ob_start();

// headers

// output

ob_end_flush();
```

Seems to be doing the trick for me.

Comment: I create a controller which loads all the files, and outputs them together with this code.

Comment: Hmm... I still don't get it - I'm not such a guru with HTTP Headers, etc. Could you please give me more complete example? I'm using several "external" `.js` scripts, I'm importing within a View the usual way (`<script></script>`). Where should the controller be called? Does it simply `echo` the `.js` files' content? (after `ob_start` I mean...)

Comment: OK, I finally made it work - although I'm definitely not sure how I did it (lol) - thought I had tried that one before (perhaps it was some issue with the cache not having being cleared before re-testing? - don't know...) Pff... Thanks a lot, anyway, buddy! ;-)

Comment: Personally, I just have an array of the paths to the files, loop with `readfile()` and only include one "js" file which is the php controller outputting everything.